# Why GPS tags are lost after saving images to PC with KIES?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, gps, samsung-kies, geotagging

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S and latest Kies downloaded from samsung site. When I save images to PC all GPS tags are elliminated. How to keep them intact?

Answer (score 2):

Copy the files directly by mounting your device storage to the PC, don't use Kies.  See GAThrawn's comment for details (thanks!).

Comment: Note that you may need  to change your phone's connection settings under "Settings", "Wireless and Network", "USB Settings" and set it to "Mass Storage" mode to do this. It will then work just like a normal digital camera or USB stick when you plug it into your PC, you should be able to find your photos in a "DCIM\Camera" folder.

Comment: I did that, there are no GPS tags in the images even I right click them to view the properties directly from the phone connected as USB storage. Do they keep GPS tags apart from the images and show them in phone gallery only?

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy It's possible ... I don't know why they'd do that :/

Comment: it is possible to check by renaming the image in the phone or making its copy